# Whatever happened to "eyeglasses", "facial tissues", and "video game consoles"?

Tags: contractions, compounds, neologisms, abbreviations

Now-a-days, we tend to ask:"Have you seen my *glasses* anywhere?" "Do you have any spare *tissues* to lend me?" and "How many *consoles* do you own?"

It's just quicker to say and any native speaker will understand, despite the (possible) ambiguity of these terms; e.g., *Where are my glasses?* could be interpreted as *Where are my drinking vessels?* But in real life, this never happens.

Essentially, I have three questions:

- When did the shortened names; **glasses**, **tissues** and **consoles** first appear and took over from their longer named "parents"?
- Is there a name for this type of noun which originally began as a compound word (sometimes joined by a hyphen) and was eventually reduced to a single-word?
- Are there any other compound nouns which have dropped one or more lexemes but still retain their original meanings?

NB: I am not referring to ***portmanteau words*** which are neologisms made by blending two words together such as *smoke* and *fog* to obtain *smog*. Neither would I consider them to be **contractions** because there is no omission of internal letters for example; *gov't*, *govt*, *gov* and *dep't* or *dept*. I can only think of "shortened" which fits the bill but can also stand for contractions; unless I am mistaken.

Despite skimming through the relevant Wikipedia pages, I found no explanation or references as to *why*, (although I think that is easily explained) or *when*, these names were shortened and became more popular.

Source Wikipedia: [***eyeglasses***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasses); [***facial tissues***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_handkerchiefs); [***video game consoles***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console).

EDIT: In my original title I had included "tissue paper" but as several users have commented, tissue paper is used for wrapping delicate objects whereas tissues normally sold in boxes are commonly referred to as *facial tissues*, especially in the US.

Comment: How about kleenex, hoovering as synonyms for tissue and vacuuming

Comment: A closely related example: _spectacles_ becomes _specs_ (which is closer to a contraction, but nobody would write _spec's_).

Comment: @mplungjan  In my opinion they used to be more popular in the past. I don't think the "young generation" uses those expressions any more.

Comment: *Tissue paper* is for wrapping delicate items in, not for blowing your nose.

Comment: @KitFox Have a look at the wiki link. Tissue paper is also used for handkerchiefs.

Comment: @Mari *Was* used for handkerchiefs. I only point it out because it has a specific meaning now which is different than *tissues*.

Comment: Also, _knickers,_ shortening of _knickerbockers,_ and _hose_ (which is a word in its own right but usually meaning _pantyhose_ now – other hosiery is usually called _stockings._)

Comment: @KitFox I remember when they were first marketed, initially everyone called them kleenex because they were sold in boxes, but then they became known as paper tissues. I'm quite certain of it, although not 100%.

Comment: I was serious, _What happened to "Using a search engine"_ now it is googling :)
@Bradd: I hear panty's here in the Netherlands for pantyhose

Comment: @mplungjan ahh! OK. Sorry. Oh, that's funny! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA "I remember ... everyone called them kleenex" - in the UK or N.America?

Comment: Tissues (paper handkerchiefs) were originally called *facial tissues*, and your question remains.

Comment: @mplungjan *Kleenex* is a brand name that continues to be protected in the US and is not supposed to be used generically for facial tissues. Similarly *Hoover* is a protected brand name and the company would resist the use of the term *hoovering* (which is not common in the US).

Comment: @Bib we do not all live in the US - however https://www.google.com/search?q=%22use%20a%20kleenex%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en

Comment: @TrevorD My question has no references to *Kleenex* so I'd prefer the discussion be kept on track. Saying that, I do remember the brand being sold and I'm pretty sure customers would just call the box of tissues by its brand name. This was in the UK. I also seem to recall that when the disposable pocket-sized packets first came out, they were referred to as *paper or handkerchief tissues* Not sure which, I could be wrong, and unfortunately I didn't find any wiki articles which may back up my childhood memories.

Comment: And one last thing, the main focus of my question is how compound nouns are over time and for convenience's sake reduced to one word, while still maintaining their original meaning. :)

Comment: The antecedent for "tissues" isn't "tissue paper" (which is a different animal, as others have commented), but "facial tissues". Most boxes of Kleenex and other brands of the stuff are still labeled this way.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my question, I didn't realize there were so many different types. To tell the truth I was thinking of those individual packets which you carry with you, not the large boxes. I've triple checked (!!!) and they are called pocket tissues. I will now make amends. :)

Comment: @JPmiaou The *immediate* antecedent for "tissues" may be "facial tissues", but it appears that that in turn had the antecedent of "tissue paper". "Tissue paper was used by musicians in the early 1900s to play the comb" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapping_tissue); but "The first tissue handkerchiefs were introduced in the 1920s" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_paper#Facial_tissues).

Comment: I'm a guy, so I wouldn't know about these things, but I just call everything either stockings or socks.

Answer (score 1):

Brief comments on selected items (including some from the comments):

#### Eye glasses

I call mine **glasses** or **specs**.

I would think of **an eyeglass** (singular) as usually referring to a *single lens*, more like an old-fashioned monocle.

> Chambers [defines](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=eyeglass&title=21st) **eyeglass *noun*** as:
>   1. a single lens in a frame, to assist weak sight.
>   2. (**eyeglasses**) *chiefly US* spectacles.

I wouldn't have said that "eyeglasses" has been a common *British* term for "spectacles" during my lifetime (>60y).

#### Tissue paper

I agree with @KitFox's comment that "*Tissue paper* is for wrapping delicate items in, not for blowing your nose". I would suggest that that is the current common British usage for "tissue paper", as confirmed by the following definition:

> Chambers [defines](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tissue&title=21st) **tissue *noun*** as:
>   1. ...  *muscle tissue*.
>   2. a piece of thin soft disposable paper used as a handkerchief or as toilet paper.
>   3. (also **tissue paper**) fine thin soft paper, used eg for wrapping fragile objects.
>   4. fine thin delicate woven fabric.
>   5. an interwoven mass or collection • *a tissue of lies*.

(I have never previously associated *tissues* with telling lies!)
I don't recall *tissues* being referred to as *tissue paper*. Nor do I recall them being referred to as *Kleenex ™* in the UK. Chambers [gives](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=kleenex&title=21st) the etymology for *Kleenex* as 1920s, whereas *tissue* [dates](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tissue&title=21st) "from 14c: from French *tissu* woven cloth". (I briefly wondered whether *[tissue](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tissue&title=21st)* was derived from *[atishoo](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=atishoo&title=21st)*, before I thought about the other meanings of *tissue*!)

The Wikipedia article you refer to [states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_paper#Hygienic_tissue_paper) that

> ... tissue paper as we know it today was not produced in USA before the mid-1940s. In Western Europe large scale industrial production started in the beginning of 1960s.

so I would suggest that the term *tissues* (in the UK) dates from the 1960s.

#### Knicker

Chambers [suggests](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tissue&title=21st) that **knickers** may have different meanings on either side of 'the pond':

> **knickerbockers** and (*US*) **knickers** ***plural noun***
>   baggy trousers tied just below the knee or at the ankle.
>
> **knickers** ***plural noun***
>   an undergarment with two separate legs or legholes. They are worn by women and girls, and cover part or all of the lower abdomen and buttocks and sometimes the thighs.

The term *knickers* is still in common use in the UK, for the second meaning given above, along with:

**[panties](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=panties&title=21st) *plural noun***

> thin light knickers, mainly for women and children.

but **[pantyhose](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=pantyhose&title=21st)** is very definitely a N.American term:

> **panty hose** or **pantihose** ***plural noun***
>    *N Amer* women's tights.

for what, in the UK, are known as **[tights](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=tights&title=21st)**:

> **tights** ***plural noun***
>   a close-fitting, usually nylon or woollen, garment which covers the feet, legs and body up to the waist, and is worn usually by women, as well as dancers and acrobats, etc.

Comment: But surely the origins of *glasses* comes from *eyeglasses* or *eye glasses* regardless of whether the expression was invented (so to speak) in the US? Eyeglasses must have *preceded* glasses.

Comment: Note that in the US, *tights* are a different animal than *[panty]hose*. The former are much thicker and probably opaque, whereas the latter are see-through and acquire runs if you look at them cross-eyed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Must have?  I can't find any evidence to support your assumption that *eyeglasses* preceded *glasses* (in the relevant sense).  Can you explain why you think this is true?

Comment: @snailboat  I had always assumed so, I knew the word *eyeglasses* existed alongside spectacles and had naturally presumed (for years and years) it preceded *glasses*. I had never done any research on the matter, nor did I think of checking its history before writing this question. (Nevertheless it very interesting if it proves to be the case.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't mean to imply that *eyeglasses* didn't precede *glasses*. I was merely quoting what I found regarding current usage. Have done a bit more research and will post more later.

Comment: I found this thread looking for ethymology of _atishoo_ as I thought it was - conversely - derived from _tissue_ actually. Just as if the sneezing person tried to ask someone "a tissue please!" but wouldn't be able to finish the phrase before the burst interrupted them. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of examples in the field of technology. Consider

> [stereo](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/stereo) (from *stereo or stereophonic system*): *a set of electronic equipment with two speakers, used for listening to the radio, CDs, and cassettes*
>
> [laptop](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laptop?view=uk) (from *laptop computer*): *a computer that is portable and suitable for use while travelling*
>
> [tablet](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tablet?view=uk) (from *tablet computer or tablet PC*): *a small portable computer that accepts input directly on to its screen rather than via a keyboard or mouse*

There are a number of terms that were not quite compound nouns, but complex nouns utilizing prefixes and roots that have been reduced to their prefix, for example

> [auto](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/auto?view=uk) (for automobile): *car*
>
> [semi](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/semitrailer#semitrailer_1) (for semitrailer): *a type of trailer or articulated lorry that has wheels only at the rear, the front end being supported by the towing vehicle*

SUPPLEMENT

The term *[cable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cable?view=uk)* also fits into the first category

> short for cable television: *I watch polo on cable*

There are also terms that take a part of the compound term (usually the adjectival noun) and make a shorter term by adding *s* and dropping the common noun

> [sweats](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sweats) (from *sweatshirt, sweatpants or sweat-suit*): *sweatshirts and sweat-suit trousers - jeans and sweats*
>
> [rubbers](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rubber?q=rubbers#rubber__4) (from *rubber boots*): *North American - rubber boots; galoshes*